# Create Image modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm Trying to create an image modal in my app! I want to create a modal such as this link - https://codepen.io/koolhaus/pen/ajwcE
Here is my code:

```css
.portfolio-list a:after {
  color: #ffff;
  content: '\f067';
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) center center no-repeat;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class=" portfolio-container text-center">
  <ul class="portfolio-list" style="margin:0 auto">
    <li style="margin:0 auto">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="{{$img['image']}}">
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How I can Add modal in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Bootstrap Modal:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Small Modal</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Small Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <img src="http://minisoft.com.bd/uploads/ourteam/rafiq.jpg" width="100%" height="320px">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

My reference     **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/nelsonfeel/x4z7f7pr/)**

keep your div in side modal-body. I kept it once check out in your local host. don't forget to add references to html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you create modal box that show image But I have image that when click in show Hello div Example

Comment: didn't get you, When click on an image then hello div open??